# Why doesn't width override max-width

Tags: width, css

If I have the following code

```
<div></div>

div
{
    background: pink;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 20px;
    width: 200px;    
}
```

The result is a div with width of 20px. (Even if I add `!important` to the width value)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/KgD5H/1/)**

Why doesn't the width property override max-width here?

Comment: It won't. what are you trying to achieve.??

Comment: I know that it won't, I'm asking why. Is this specified somewhere?

Comment: Refer this: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-width

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `max-width` has more priority than `width`. Its function is to prevent `width` of an element to increase from certain boundaries. If you want `width` to override `max-width` then remove `max-width`.

[A good link to refer given in comments](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-width)